# combine two bytes to form signed value (16 bit)

Tags: python, binary, binary-data

I want to combine two bytes `(8 bit)` to form a signed value `(one bit for sign and 15 for the value)` according to the two complement's method.
I receive `MSbyte` (note that the most left bit of MSByte is for the sign) and the `LSbyte`. So I write a function by shifting the `MSByte` to the left by `8 bit` then I add it with the `LSByt`e to form a binary sequence of `16 bit`. Then, I calculate the `ones'complement`, and I finally add 1 to the result. However, it does not work.

```
def twos_comp_two_bytes(msb, lsb):
    a= (msb<<8)+ lsb
    r = ~(a)+1
    return r
```

For example `0b0b1111110111001001` is `-567` however with the above function I get `-64969`.

EDIT :  call of the function

```
twos_comp_two_bytes(0b11111101,0b11001001) => -64969
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.7/c-api/bytearray.html)?, for instance`bytearray(msb+lsb)`

Comment: Is your data ``bytes`` or ``int`` or something else?

Comment: my data is in the form of 0b....'

Comment: ``0b....`` (an int) or ``'0b....'`` (a str)?

Comment: I receive bytearrey(1) for MSB and bytearray(1) for LSB in my code

Comment: If you have bytearray, why is your example call using ints?

Comment: it's binary not int i guess

Comment: Python has no binary type, that's why we're asking. ``0b11111101`` is an integer *literal*, the result of Python would show to you as just ``253``. There is no standard type that Python would display like a binary number.

Comment: `r = a - (256*256)` and you get `-567`

Comment: simpler: `struct.unpack('h', bytes([lsb, msb]))` gives -567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses integers which may have any lenght - they are not restricted to `16bits` so to get `-567` it would need rather

```
r = a - (256*256)
```

but it need more code for other values

```
def twos_comp_two_bytes(msb, lsb):
    a = (msb<<8) + lsb
    if a >= (256*256)//2:
        a = a - (256*256)
    return a

print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b11111101, 0b11001001))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b0, 0b0))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b0, 0b1))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b10000000, 0b0))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b10000000, 0b1))
```

Results:

```
-567
0
1
-32768
-32767
```

---

It would be better to use special module [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for this

```
import struct

def twos_comp_two_bytes(msb, lsb):
    return struct.unpack('>h', bytes([msb, lsb]))[0]  
    #return struct.unpack('<h', bytes([lsb, msb]))[0] # different order `[lsb, msb]`
    #return struct.unpack( 'h', bytes([lsb, msb]))[0] # different order `[lsb, msb]`

print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b11111101, 0b11001001))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b0, 0b0))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b0, 0b1))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b10000000, 0b0))
print(twos_comp_two_bytes(0b10000000, 0b1))
```

Results:

```
-567
0
1
-32768
-32767
```

---

Letter `h` means `short integer` (signed `int` with 2 bytes).

Char `>`, `<` describes order of bytes.

See more in [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)